# bcrypt login is not working in production while works on localhost

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, passport-local

I used the user model like below:
the usermodel uses bcrypt authentication and is working fine over the localhost.
In the production, the registration works fine and while registering the user gets logged in. However, in the login it gives the error "Either Username or Password is wrong".

```
var mongoose              = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var bcrypt                = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var userSchema            = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email  : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password  : {type: String},
    twitterId : String,
    twitterToken: String,
    profileUserName: String,
    displayName : String,
    coachingUser: Boolean,
    coaching_name: String,
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  var SALT_FACTOR = 5;
  console.log("in the presave method");
  if (!user.isModified('password')) 
    {
        //console.log("in the presave method");
        return next();
    }

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        console.log("in the presave method");
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });});});
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    console.log("candidatePassword: " + candidatePassword);
    console.log(this.password);
    var passlen = this.password;
console.log("password length: " + passlen.length);
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    console.log("isMatch: " + isMatch);
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};`
module.exports  = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

in the localhost, the bcrypt login is working fine. However in the production over https://mlab.com/home and digitalocean, the login always gives Email or password not correct.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!user) {
        //console.log(user);
        req.flash("error", "Either Username or Password is wrong");
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      {
        //console.log(user);
        req.flash("success","Successfully logged in as " + user.username);
        res.redirect('/coaching');
    }
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Kindly provide help as to why in production the particular logic not work

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: log does not show any error.

Comment: log does not show any error.
There was one answer where the length of password field has to be 60 for bcrypt then 45. How do we test the size of the password field. Can anyone please share the query. and also how to set it to 60?

Comment: I'm finding the same thing. I'm thinking it boils down to the fingerprint created when creating the password. Used locally, it works great. When on the production server, for some reason the signing of the passoword, originally, is different. It's like they (bcrypt) have two secrets or fingerprints. Odd, haven't solved it, but seeing it now